# Why not take two emails?

Tags: feature-request, survey-2018

I just completed the Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2018. The last question asked if I mind being contacted directly. I wanted to enter two emails but it would not let me. I tried:

> t1@dada.com;t2@mydomain.in

and also tried:

> t1@dada.com t2@mydomain.in
>
> t1@dada.com and t2@mydomain.in

Maybe next year allow two boxes, or change the validation?

Why two emails - sometimes I check the first and not the other, and other times due to work I check the second and not the first.

Comment: So, send it to your personal account and just check your mail after work? It's not like SO is going to send you time-sensitive mail.

Comment: @cerbrus yes that would work. i just like the feature so suggested it. we have it in a product we made and it helps is all. i will delete this question in a few hours as it was so well received :-)

Comment: You don't need to delete the request. In fact, it is better if you don't. That way, we can refer users with similar requests back to this one.

Comment: A few years back I posted about relevant ads on stackoverflow even if logged in, and i think it went to -30! but now we have ads.So maybe in a few years they will add this too. Nothing technically challenging and I don't see much of a down side besides the email server sending two emails

Answer (score 13):

This is a problem on your side.

I do value you not wanting to check your private mail during work time and vice versa, but why would Stack Overflow have to fix that for you by allowing to enter multiple email addresses?

You could set up a forwarder for certain keywords, for example. Or you could check your private mail on your smartphone. Or you could wait until you got home to check and reply to the mail.

Comment: Its not about not wanting to. Its about not being able to. Anyway meta is all about down votes for me. A few years back I posted about relevant ads on stackoverflow even if logged in, and i think it went to -30! but now we have ads. I know about  forwarding rules etc. I still like my feature :) Good day